# Is there no flowchart or data flow diagram for Windows Installer actions and how they relate to each other?

Tags: c#, wix, installation, windows-installer, custom-action

While working on Windows installer packages using [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/), I find it extremely cumbersome to have to keep searching for access points with my C# custom actions. For example, say I have an action that I want to take place before files are installed, after the installation happens, before the installation, before the installation but before any other actions, before any progress bar is visible, etc.

Isn't there some sort of flow-chart of better representation of data flow or action flow between [actions that occur during Windows installer's MSI installations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372023(v=vs.85).aspx) and how they relate to one another? I know this would be a huge help for me and other installation package developers, because I haven't been able to find anything like this while searching online.

**Edit**: [This](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/standard-actions.html) has been the best resource I have been able to find so far.

Answer (score 2):

This is my goto article for the last 13 years:

[Installation Phases and In-Script Execution Options for Custom Actions in Windows Installer](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/)

Being on a team of Windows Installer experts provides a great mentoring opportunity to pick up all this trivia and put it into the proper context.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://installpac.wordpress.com/2008/04/09/windows-installer-sequencing/) a while back it helped to understand the sequences of the MSIExec action sequence

Comment: Not a whole lot of detail to that chart. Especially if you only look at the core scenario (install) that most people care about.